# Jetpack Compose navigation with arguments

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to navigate from ViewModelOne to ViewModelTwo where I send data to ViewModelTwo during navigation.
This is my navigation sealed class with route and ID argument

```
sealed class AnimationsNavigation : NavigationAction {
    class PopUpAnimationNavigation(val id: String = "{id}") : AnimationsNavigation() {
        override val route: String
            get() = "animationNavigator/$id"
    }
}
```

This is my example compose holder, where I pass my backStackEntry

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.composableHolder(
    action: NavigationAction,
    content: @Composable (NavBackStackEntry) -> Unit
) {
    composable(
        route = action.route,
    ) { navBackStack->
        content(navBackStack)
    }
}
```

And this is where I used it

```
private fun NavGraphBuilder.commonDestinations() {
    composableHolder(AnimationsNavigation.PopUpAnimationNavigation()){
        AnimationsNavigator()
    }
}
```

This is the viewModel I am navigating with the argument I will pass to other screen where I eventually will use it

```
class OrderDetailScreenViewModel(
    private val navigationDispatcher: NavigationDispatcher
) : ViewModel() {
    
    fun confirmButtonClicked() {
        navigateToAnimation()
    }

    private fun navigateToAnimation() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            navigationDispatcher.navigateTo(AnimationsNavigation.PopUpAnimationNavigation(id = "here will be posible id"))
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the viewModel I am trying to get it

```
class AnimationsViewModel(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
    
    init {
        val id = savedStateHandle.get<String>("id").orEmpty()
    }
}
```

The problem is that I always get empty string like SaveStateHandle is empty (I saw part of this way for navigation and adapt it to my app), any ideas how I can pass data like that?

Comment: Seems like when you pass `action.route` to `composable`, it's always the route to navigate, e.g. "animationNavigator/10". But in order for arguments to work, you need to pass placeholdered route, e.g. "animationNavigator/{id}" into `composable` and only pass "animationNavigator/10" into `navigate`. Check out more in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args)

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, because when I try to get it in `composableHolder` everything is ok, like this
 `composableHolder(AnimationsNavigation.PopUpAnimationNavigation()) {
        val id = it.arguments?.getString("id")
        AnimationsNavigator()
    }
` , I just think this `SavedStateHandle` is not working as I use it.